# Difference between CatchAccessDeniedException and SuppressAccessDeniedRedirectInScope in Sharepoint

Tags: exception, sharepoint-2010, access-denied

Do they both do the same?

Or is there a difference in the behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SuppressAccessDeniedRedirectInScope` is a class that implements `IDisposable`.  The constructor stores the original value of `CatchAccessDeniedException` and sets the value to `false` to suppress the automatic redirect within the using scope.  The `Dispose` method restores the original value of `CatchAccessDeniedException`.